# If the answer to my question is a partial solution, am I OK to rename the question rather than posting another?

Tags: discussion

An answer to my question fixed an issue with a library but the library still isn't working as intended. Am I better off to alter the question or post a new one?

The question I am referring is [Is there a library for loading in SVG layers to an Mac OS X application using Objective-C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10365121/is-there-a-library-for-loading-in-svg-layers-to-an-osx-app-using-objective-c)

Comment: It looks like you're new to Meta; welcome! FYI, [votes work differently here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#vote-differences).

Comment: Beware not to create ["Camelion Questions"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions)... They can be quite annoying...

Comment: +1 for asking at Meta before slipping into "chameleon" question swamp

Comment: Could you report the link to the question you are referring? Without that, you are going to get just generic answers, or answers taking some assumptions. In both the cases, this very question would not be useful to future users, without knowing the actual question for which you are interested.

Comment: Link the the page in question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10365121/is-there-a-library-for-loading-in-svg-layers-to-an-osx-app-using-objective-c. The build that person linked me to works in the sense Xcode will build it. But doesn't function as it should

Answer (score 10):

If your question has been answered, accept the post that answered it and post a new one.

It's not fair to other users to fundamentally change your question in a way that makes previously valid answers invalid. (It's also very annoying.)

A question is just that: a question. If it requires more than one question to solve a specific problem, there's no problem with that (as long as the questions are real, on topic, constructive and not too localized).

Comment: It seems you are taking the assumption that the issue fixed by the answer was the only issue with the library. Without seeing the actual question, it's difficult to say. Generally speaking, saying to ask a new question is not what I would suggest. Your suggested workflow is accepting a partial answer, and asking a new question. I guess the new question should exclude the already answered part, if that is possible. How much questions would the user ask before to get a complete answer?

Answer (score 2):

> Am I better off to alter the question or post a new one?

If the answer you get partially answer your question, I would leave a comment to that answer pointing out that the answer is only partial. If the user doesn't update the answer, then you can:

- Accept the answer.
- Write your own answer that complements the one already given, and accept the other user's answer because it helped you to find the solution.
- Wait for somebody else to write a more complete answer.

It's not obligatory to accept an answer, especially if you are not satisfied with the given answer. There isn't a timeout after which you need to accept an answer; if a complete answer is given after 15 days, you can wait 15 days.

Rewriting the question would be wrong if there are already other answers given for your question, and which would be not more valid, if the question is edited.
If there is just an answer, and it is the partial answer you are referring, editing your question to remove the part that has not been answered is up to you; I would not do that just to be able to accept the answer.
If the part that has not been answered is only marginal, then you could edit it out (if there is just an answer for your question), and ask as a different question; I would do that only if it is possible to split the question without repeating (most of) the information given in the first question.

Accepting the answer, and asking a new question that would contain the part of the old question still without an answer would not be correct, without to edit the same part out of the old question. In this case, the new question could be closed as duplicate of the other one. Editing out the part without answer could not be correct, if your question already obtained more than one answer, and at least one answer is answering that part.

If you don't rewrite your question, and you don't accept the existing answer waiting for a new, more complete answer to be given, you can consider offering a bounty for your question. In this way, it will get more attention, and probably somebody will give the complete answer you are hoping for.

#### Update

Now that you provided the link to the question in question, I can give a more precise answer. 
Your first question was how to build the library you wanted to use, while the new question is the following one:

> I managed to find a working one with help in one of the comments but the output has a green tint to it. Does anyone know what could cause this? And how to fix it?

In this case, the additional questions are a completely different question.
Your first issue was to be able to build the framework, and I take the given answer helped you with that (otherwise you would not have accepted the answer). Now you are asking why the output of the framework is not the one you would expect, which is not anymore a problem with building the framework. (Is the working framework the same one you were referring in your question?)

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, the OP refers to the case where his original question doesn't cover the whole problem, so answers that actually **do** answer the question (completely) still won't solve his problem. He wants to know if he should edit the question **or** post a new one.

Comment: He is referring to a partial answer that helps fixing an issue with the library, but the library is still not working as expected. It's the answer to be partial, not the question.

Comment: Maybe you're right (I can't tell for sure from the wording of this question), but if that were the case, the possibilities would be do nothing or edit the original question (to cut out the unanswered part) **and** post a new one. However, the OP asks whether he should do one or another.

Comment: I did answer that.

Comment: Yes, but making the assumption that the answer didn't cover the original question. Well, there's no point in arguing over this. (FWIW, the downvote isn't mine.)

Comment: I didn't make any assumption; it's what the OP said: "An answer to my question fixed an issue with a library but the library still isn't working as intended." The OP didn't say "An answer to my question fixed the issue I was having with a library." The question's title is then, "If the answer to my question is a partial solution, am I OK to rename the question rather than posting another?

Comment: Which is assuming that the original question was `Why is my library not working as intended?` and not `Why does code X not yield result Y?`. @Jamesp1989: Could we get some clarification here?

Comment: Jamesp1989 doesn't get any notification, using @Jamesp1989, as he didn't comment here.